# a not clickable in a div

Tags: html, css

I have this code

```css
.dark-bg {
  width: 30%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(58, 10, 123) 15%, rgb(67, 28, 158) 90%);
  float: left;
  z-index: 100;
}

.wave {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  bottom: 0;
  width: 30.06%;
  height: 100vh;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  background: url(https://i.imgur.com/Ds3Raj2.png);
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<a href='/hgt'>test</a>
<div class="dark-bg" }>
  <a href='/hgt'>test2</a>
</div>
<div class="wave" }>
  <a href='/hgt'>test 3</a>
</div>
```

Codepen link : https://codepen.io/bagou4502/pen/dyZYJpQ

And i can t click on test 2.
I try to add a z index but not work.

Comment: What's the `}` for in your HTML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try by adding `pointer-events:none` to the `wave` and this will prevent user to click on the `div` :

```css
.dark-bg {
  width: 30%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(58, 10, 123) 15%, rgb(67, 28, 158) 90%);
  float: left;
  z-index: 100;
}

.wave {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  bottom: 0;
  width: 30.06%;
  height: 100vh;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  background: url(https://i.imgur.com/Ds3Raj2.png);
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<a href='/hgt'>test</a>
<div class="dark-bg" }>
  <a href='/hgt'>test2</a>
</div>
<div class="wave" }>
  <a href='/hgt'>test 3</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.dark-bg {
                width: 30%;
                height: 100vh;
                background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(58, 10, 123) 15%, rgb(67, 28, 158) 90%);
                float: left;
                z-index: 100;
              }
            .wave {
                position: absolute;
                content: "";
                bottom: 0;
                width: 30.06%;
                height: 100vh;
                transform: rotate(180deg);
                background: url(https://i.imgur.com/Ds3Raj2.png);
                background-size: contain;
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                z-index: 100;
            }
a {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

```html
<a href='/hgt'>test</a>
            <div class="dark-bg" >
                <a href='/hgt'>test2</a>
            </div>
 <div class="wave" >
                <a href='/hgt'>test 3</a>
            </div>
```

One solution is to z-index the anchor tag.